# can't add all files to git due to permissions

Tags: git

I want to add all the files in the current directory to git:

```
git add .
error: open(".mysql_history"): Permission denied
fatal: unable to index file .mysql_history
```

That's fine. That file happens to be in this directory and owned by root. I want to add all *other* files.  Is there a way to do that without having to manually add each file by hand?

I know that I could add the file to exclude or .gitignore, but I'd like to have it just ignore things based on permissions (there's a good chance other files like this will end up in the directory, and adding them to .gitignore all the time is a pain).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use `git add --ignore-errors .`

This will still give an error for the unreadable file(s), but not a fatal one. The other files will be added.

Comment: If you are using VS this can happen. In my case I had to close all Visual Studio instances. Shutting down IIS Express and restarting Visual Studio will also solve the issue.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 this was the answer for me! Far easier than creating a .gitignore and adding the file like many other suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Closing your IDE or whatever that uses the relative files you want to upload solved my problem

Answer (score 8):

As [@Dhanuka777 pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356323/cant-add-all-files-to-git-due-to-permissions/70923886#comment62060185_359696), if you are using Visual Studio or Unity, you have to shutdown all Visual Studio and Unity instances before doing `git add .`

Comment: Is there any other way?

Answer (score 6):

Would it help if you added that file to your .gitignore file?  So all other files would be versioned and that file would get ignored (unless you need it).

Answer (score 4):

Just exclude the file. You can add `.mysql_history` to a `.gitignore` file, or add it to `.git/info/exclude`.

Adding an entry to `.gitignore` will propagate the setting with the repo (since `.gitignore` is stored with the repo); adding it to `.git/info/exclude` makes it "personal" because this file is *not* propagated with the repo. Either way, `.mysql_history` will be ignored by `git-add` and friends.

You can read more about ignoring files with Git on this [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo chown $(whoami): .git/objects/ -R; git add --ignore-errors .
```

fixed it for me. The first half fixed ownership, (someone checked-in as root, naughty) and the second half makes errors non-fatal. The second half on its own helped me track down which directory was owned by root.

Answer (score 3):

I was using [@matli's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359696/2745495) but still having troubles sometimes.

I ended up using

```
git add --ignore-errors --force .
```

Answer (score 2):

Closed all instances of visual studio worked for me

Answer (score 2):

you can change directory permission to ignore this error :
e.g. `sudo chmod -R 777 directory`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to add excel file to git, but those excel file where opened, hence 'git add' was trying to add the $filename.xlsx(the file which gets created along side the original file while we are working on an opened instance of that file).Closing the excel file worked for me

Comment: I had same issue on Windows 11 machine. I checked this message late after already trying this solution that fixed the error. I want to add that this worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is some task/process related to those files running in background.

I realised trying to empty my Temp folder. When a file cannot be erased, Windows informs you which is the process related to. Killing that process solved me the problem.

That's why finishing the IDE or restarting the system usually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 755 file.xxx
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**The first thing you have to know that why the error occures?
This mainly due to git command running on un related file group or a file that is owned by root or its own but you need an allivated access. This is mainly in Linux.**

If this for windows try using file/folder property setting and adding user to the list of permission.

**In linux you have mainly three(3) options.**

**1. run git as**

```
> sudo git add .
```

**2. run git command as**

```
git add --ignore-errors  -force .
```

**3. change file or folder who is issuing permission deniedn with sudo access or default user account.**

```
chmod 755 /direcroty/file.html
```

4. adjuts your curernt user account to access denied file evenif,with sudor permsiions and adjustemnt.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I was standing in the wrong folder. i.e. I was standing in a folder that is inside the main git repo.

Answer (score -2):

Please Specify file name you want to add;
example:

```
git add index.html
```

I hope this helps you also

Answer (score -3):

Restarting system (Windows) solving my problem.

Answer (score -3):

This idiot (me) tried to add files to git that were on onedrive (terrible place for a git repo I know), without onedrive running...